# Как сделать выборку из базы данных каждого одного значения по максимальной дате

Tags: sql

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| cycle | data                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| 1     | 21.01.2018 (Максимальная дата)              |
| 1     | 15.01.2018                                  |
| 1     | 10.01.2018                                  |
| 2     | 20.01.2018 (Максимальная дата)              |
| 2     | 11.01.2018                                  |
| 2     | 01.01.2018                                  |
| 3     | 25.01.2018 (Максимальная дата)              |
| 3     | 21.01.2018                                  |
| 3     | 23.01.2018                                  |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Как мне сделать SQL запрос, чтобы он мне выдал по одному из значений Cycle по максимальной дате и чтобы я получил такой ответ:

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| cycle | data                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| 1     | 21.01.2018 (Максимальная дата)              |
| 2     | 20.01.2018 (Максимальная дата)              |
| 3     | 25.01.2018 (Максимальная дата)              |
+-------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Обязательно, чтобы были все данные из ячейки Cycle, как в примере выше.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так `SELECT cycle, MAX(data) AS data FROM table GROUP BY cycle;`

Comment: Забыли псевдоним для второго столбца

Comment: @Anamnian точно)